# Should "thirst" be pluralized in the phrase "quench their thirst(s)"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number, abstract-nouns

I am unsure of whether or not I should be using "thirst" or "thirsts" in this sentence:

> When Moses led the people out of Egypt and into the desert, didn’t the Lord command Moses to strike a rock so that water would flow and quench their **thirst**?

Do I pluralize *thirst* because it is had by multiple people, or do I keep it singular because they only thirst for a single thing (water)?

Comment: Conventional usage (at least in the US) would be to only use the plural for multiple substances (and even then it would be iffy).

Comment: You would pluralize thirst if there were different thirsts. For example, if some of the people thirsted for release from enslavement, others thirsted for freedom to worship as they wished, and still others thirsted for the ability to choose their own leaders, then it might be reasonable to use "thirsts" in the sentence. It would only work, though, if the reader/listener understood that there were these different yearnings among the people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not pluralised. Thirst is an abstract quality and does not change. The people were having thirst, but the thirst was not multiple. They were not having thirst A, or thirst B, or thirst C et cetera.

As in-

> I, my mother, my father, and my children are having ***good health.***

Here, each person is not having a separate health- **health A, health B, health C....** Because ***health*** is an abstract noun, and it is not pluralised.

Comment: why "are having"? "have" seems to be better here, unless you imply that that good health is only temporary

Comment: And why *a good health*? It should be just *good health*, because *health* is an abstract, uncountable, noun.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, in standard English in most of the English-speaking world, that would be written:  (1) "The people were thirsting," not "The people were having thirst"; (2) "They did not have thirst A", not "They were not having thirst A"; (3) "I, my mother, my father, and my children are in good health," not "I, my mother, my father, and my children are having good health."